# Event get value by separated with bind to each handle. is it possible?

Tags: jquery

I'm making filters
I want that when you push about the event of each one of these elements get its value. It would with bind ()
do I an event different for each of these 3 elements?

```
HTML Code:

<input type = "text" id='filter_reference'> <select id='filter_status'> <input type = "date" id="datepicker"> //Is a datepicker
```

example:

```
$("#filter_reference, #filter_status, #datepicker").bind("focus keypress", function(){
     var optionselected = $(this).find("option:selected");
     var valueselected = optionselected.val();
     var filtro = $(this).attr('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work for `<input>` as you're just taking the value of `option:selected`, which only concerns with the `<select>`

You can just use `.val()` to get the value of even `<select>` without targeting `option:selected` and it will work for the `<input>` as well.

```
$("#filter_reference, #filter_status, #datepicker").bind("focus keypress", function(){
     var valueselected = $(this).val(); // this would suffice
     var filtro = $(this).attr('id');
});
```